# Prove that $\frac{d}{dy}\int\limits_{0}^1f(x,y)dm(x)=\int\limits_0^1\frac{df}{dy}dm(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded funtion. Suppose that for
>   each fixed $y$, the map $x\to f(x,y)$ is a measurable function of $x$.
>   Suppose the partial derivative $\frac{df}{dy}$ exists at every point
>   of $[0,1]^2$ and defines a bounded function o $[0,1]^2$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{d}{dy}\int\limits_{0}^1f(x,y)dm(x)=\int\limits_0^1\frac{df}{dy}dm(x)$$.

**My attempt:**
$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dy}\int\limits_{0}^1f(x,y)dm(x) &=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\int\limits_0^1f(x,y+h)-\int\limits_0^1f(x,y)}{h}\\
                         &=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\int\limits_0^1\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}  
\end{align}$

We have done several results to interchange the limit and integral when you have a sequence of functions converging pointwise almost everywhere. So to take the limit inside the integral, I'm going to use the fact that:
$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ when ever for any sequence $x_n$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=a$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=b$

This is the place I got stuck: 
So may be I can define $g(h)=\frac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}$ and for $(h_n)$ such that $h_n\to0$ $g_n=g(h_n)$ ?or I might be wrong.
Appreciate your help to complete the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x,y+h)-f(x,y)}{h}\right|&=\left|\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\eta_{x,y,h})\right|\leq M
\end{align*}
as the assumption is given that the partial is bounded, here $\eta_{x,y,h}$ is chosen by Mean Value, and we are now to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: you mean for the $g_n$ that I have defined?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking you need to realize to sequential version, but anyway it will lead to the same estimate, Mean Value, to bound it.

Comment: Of course some author will take a note of non-sequential version of Lebesgue Dominated, this is nothing but just a homework exercise for realizing to the sequential version.

Comment: Thank you very much!